# htaccess redirect directory except for ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all url's from

`domain.com/incoming-dir/`   to `domain.com/direct-dir/`

I use the following for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?incoming-dir/(.*)  direct-dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now I want to build in an exception.

The redirect should not happen for an iPhone and iPad.

What should be added for this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You should check first with `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` and exclude what you want from next rule

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(iPhone|iPad).*$  [NC]
 RewriteRule ^incoming-dir/(.*)  direct-dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```